# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: Unable to resolve/ping hostname

Tags: dns, ping, hostname

I'm having 2 Odroid U3 Boards running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed samba so that I can ping both boards in Windows by their hostname. This works as expected. But I'm unable to ping Windows from one of the Odroid boards. I'm also unable to ping the other Odroid board when I'm connected to one Odroid Board.

I've added the correct nameserver to resolv.conf:

```
root@odroid1:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.2.1
```

The resolv.conf of the other board (hostname odroid2) has exactly the same resolv.conf.

But when I try to ping odroid2 from odroid1, I'm getting "unknown host odroid2":

```
root@odroid1:~# ping odroid2
ping: unknown host odroid2
```

Using dig shows me no answer:

```
root@odroid1:~# dig odroid2

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u11-Debian <<>> odroid2
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 50491
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1460
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;odroid2.                       IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       3574    IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2017060901 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 14 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 09 18:21:50 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111
```

Using dig to resolve the dns of my Windows PC has the same result.
Does anyone know what can cause the problem?

Comment: Do you have a DNS Server at 192.168.2.1? What if you ping odroid2.local?

Comment: Pinging odroid2.local also says "unknown host". 192.168.2.1 is my router, but it's only a DNS-Proxy. So I'm not absolutely sure if this may work or not. But if not, I'm a bit confused that I can ping both Odroid boards using Windows.

Comment: Did you manually edit /etc/resolv.conf? Show me `ps auxc | grep dns` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Thanks heynnema for the support. I finally found the solution in this thread: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ping-netbios-names-from-linux-samba-271336/
I had to adjust my /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: Your /etc/resolv.conf still looks wrong though. Start new comments directed at me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema: Ok, alright :). ps auxc | grep dns is empty and ls -al /etc/resolv.conf shows `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23 Jan  1  2000 /etc/resolv.conf`. cat /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf does not exist on my Odroid. /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf does not exist on my system...

Comment: I'm confused... but if your problem is solved... who's going to complain? You just added **wins** to /etc/nsswitch.conf, yes?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, adding **wins** solved the problem for me. Thanks in advance!